# What does ++ do after the array in this function?

Tags: c, arrays, operators

```
void doSomething()
{
    int hist[5] = { 0 };
    int num_bins = 5;
    int indices[10] = { 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 };
    int num_indices = 10;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_indices; i++)
    {
        hist[indices[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num_bins; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", hist[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Assume I have correct libraries this is a conceptual question from class. I am wondering how the answer comes out to 2 0 1 4 3 for the array.

Comment: What do you think it should be? -- and you should try to step through the code line by line with a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: The `++` in `hist[indices[i]]++;` increments the value of `hist[indices[i]]` by `1` each time it is executed.

Comment: 2 zeros, 0 ones, 1 two, 4 threes and 3 fours.

Comment: `indices` tells the program which elements of `hist` to increment. `0`: increment `hist[0]`. Another `0`: increment `hist[0]` again. `2`: increment `hist[2]`. `3`: increment `hist[3]`. And so on.

Comment: `int num_bins = 5;` is more robustly written as `const int num_bins = sizeof hist / sizeof hist[0];`, and similarly for `num_indices`.

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
hist[indices[i]]++
```

Says "go to the element of the `hist` array at index `indices[i]`, then increment it."  If you think of the array as a list of counters, this says to increment the counter at position `indices[i]`.

This code builds a histogram of the frequencies of various numbers in an array.  The idea behind the above code is to iterate over the array and increment the frequencies of each element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The elements in `indices` range from `0` to `4`, which are all valid index of the 5 elements array `hist`. (That's why the array is named `indices`, as it's for indexing)

So for instance, `i` is `2`, then `indices[i]` is `2`.

```
hist[indices[i]]++;
```

is equivalent to

```
hist[2]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

For small questions like this you should try to write down the state of every element of each array on a piece of paper and execute your code step by step. You could also write the code to print useful information in runtime.

If after that you still can't figure it out then it's worth asking here. Otherwise you won't be learning much.

Answer (score 0):

This program increments the 0's in

```
hist
```

as it indexes appear in

```
indices[10]
```

eg.

when you have the first for interation

```
hist[indices[0]]++   // hist[0]++  --> 0++;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "2 0 1 4 3" is a count of how many items exists in the array. 2 0's, 0 1's, 1 2, 4 3's and 3 4's. So the query is counting how many instances of each number are in the array and then printing out that result.

So the statement:

```
hist[indices[i]]++
```

find the value of indices[], then increments the int in the hist[] array by 1 giving you a count of how many of those elements are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

1.As you have partially initialized your array, compiler sets other values to 0
2.hist[indices[i]]++; this statement increments the value of hist[i], for the current value of i
3.the value of i is denoted by your array indices[]
4.try having values grater than 5 in your array named indices[].